# How to save the pixels in area of the QGRaphicsItem?

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsitem

Here is the thing, I have develop a manual Annotation Tool for annotating images, you know, use rectangles to mark parts of a human, head, torso, limbs, and store the information like width, height, center point, rotation.  I use QT to develop this tiny tool, it's cool, but I face a problem. I want to save the pixels of the image which in a QGraphicsScene in the area of the rectangles (QGraphicsItems), so, I want to know how can I control the pixels of this area?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can render the rectangle area into a QPainter which can be a QImage:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#render